# Allow outside clicking of modal without closing it?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, mdbootstrap

I am trying to make a Facebook-like chat box using a modal. It works great! However, if I try to click anywhere else on the page without closing it first, nothing happens.

Before you ask, I have tried `data-backdrop="true"/"false"/"static"`. I have decided "false" works best since there is no backdrop when opened. However, it still disables any background clicks. I understand there must be some way to override the code within the Modal class to change this.

```html
<div class="modal fade left" id="ChatModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false" style="z-index: 0;">
```

Comment: According to what I researched in the documentation, `backdrop` option lets you 
either have a backdrop (true) or not (false) or have a backdrop while disabling the clicking outside of the modal (static). Which I think make sense, because if you disabled clicking outside of the modal and not having a backdrop to block the content of on the web page, what would happen when user clicks the content on the web page outside of the modal?

Comment: It would be as if the modal wasn't open. That's what I want though. I want for the modal to overlay the page as usual, but for me to be able to click around the page as if it wasn't there.